# Sending and receiving packets over the internet securely

Tags: android, network-programming, raspberry-pi

I'm new to any sort of programming for networks, and would like a little advice before I start.

I would like to run a server (Raspberry Pi) at home, which I would like to be able to contact to run particular programs/scripts and to trigger other events on my home network (WoL, home automation stuff etc)

I would like to be able to contact it independently of the platform - i.e. from Android & Windows primarily, iOS and Linux perhaps.

I would like to have some sort of security, in that I don't want anyone else to be able to contact my RPi and operate it.

Is there some sort of standard interface that is used for this sort of thing?  I was thinking of running Apache, but thought I'd check there aren't more targeted solutions available first.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure Socket Shell (ssh) would be my suggestion.  It's already installed under RPi AFAIK, but you probably want to generate a public/private keypair and only permit login to your server using the keypair (i.e. disable password authentication). Also restrict the *allowed users* to you alone.  Don't do this as root; instead create some setuid scripts to perform any admin-only tasks within the server and restrict the access control on those scripts.

One more tip to avoid constant crack attempts: move the port from 22 to 422 (which could be done using the NAT config of your internet router).

You could probably use [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/), however for some client platforms you might be able to get away with a shell script implementation.

Comment: For shell-like, or arbitrary access, the solution would probably be of this form.  However, for simple controls/status, especially to use from arbitrary/smartphone clients, a secured web page with buttons and readouts could also be worth considering.  And no matter what the method, a plausible security design can be broken by one, little overlooked flaw in either the custom code or the components on which it depends.

Comment: Both ideas sound good.  I like the keypair solution as it sounds secure and easier than entering a secure password on a mobile device each time.  However a secure website would mean I only have to program it once, and not for other devices I want to use it with.  Thanks for the input.